# ASP.NET : when trying to configure a SqlDataSource, the 'specify columns from table or view' option is grayed out. How to resolve this?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, database-connection

I don't have much experience with ASP.NET. I am attempting to choose which columns I want to view from a database table inside of a gridview. When I go to Configure Data Source and get to the 'Configure the Select Statement' page the only option available is to specify SQL statements from stored procedures; everything else is grayed out as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Here is the source code I have so far :

[image]

Comment: Try to Check your Database Configuration Correct or Check Table name is correct or not. Check this link for reference https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_sources.htm

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was creating a table in a database and saving the table file, but I wasn't updating it to the database. In Visual Studio 2015 when creating a table for a database you must hit the update database button (with the arrow pointing up icon) after you finish configuring the table. This can also be performed by pressing Shift+Alt+U.